# Dictionary in python will not print completely (is versus ==)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am having issues printing out the following dict in my python code.

```
status = {"1.1.1":"FAIL","1.1.1.1":"FAIL","1.1.1.2":"FAIL","1.1.1.3":"FAIL","1.1.1.4":"FAIL","1.1.1.5":"FAIL","1.1.1.6":"FAIL","1.1.1.7":"FAIL","1.1.1.8":"FAIL","1.1.10":"FAIL","1.1.11":"FAIL","1.1.12":"FAIL","1.1.13":"FAIL","1.1.14":"FAIL","1.1.15":"FAIL","1.1.16":"FAIL","1.1.17":"FAIL","1.1.18":"FAIL","1.1.19":"FAIL","1.1.2":"FAIL","1.1.20":"FAIL","1.1.21":"FAIL","1.1.3":"FAIL","1.1.4":"FAIL","1.1.5":"FAIL","1.1.6":"FAIL","1.1.7":"FAIL","1.1.8":"FAIL","1.1.9":"FAIL","1.2.1":"FAIL","1.2.2":"FAIL","1.3.1":"FAIL","1.3.2":"FAIL","1.4.1":"FAIL","1.4.2":"FAIL","1.4.3":"FAIL","1.5.1":"FAIL","1.5.2":"FAIL","1.5.3":"FAIL","1.5.4":"FAIL","1.6.1":"FAIL","1.6.1.1":"FAIL","1.6.1.2":"FAIL","1.6.1.3":"FAIL","1.6.1.4":"FAIL","1.6.2":"FAIL","1.6.2.1":"FAIL","1.6.2.2":"FAIL","1.6.3":"FAIL","1.7.1":"FAIL","1.7.1.1":"FAIL","1.7.1.2":"FAIL","1.7.1.3":"FAIL","1.7.1.4":"FAIL","1.7.1.5":"FAIL","1.7.1.6":"FAIL","1.7.2":"FAIL","2.1.1":"FAIL","2.1.10":"FAIL","2.1.2":"FAIL","2.1.3":"FAIL","2.1.4":"FAIL","2.1.5":"FAIL","2.1.6":"FAIL","2.1.7":"FAIL","2.1.8":"FAIL","2.1.9":"FAIL","2.2.1.1":"FAIL","2.2.1.2":"FAIL","2.2.1.3":"FAIL","2.2.10":"FAIL","2.2.11":"FAIL","2.2.12":"FAIL","2.2.13":"FAIL","2.2.14":"FAIL","2.2.15":"FAIL","2.2.16":"FAIL","2.2.17":"FAIL","2.2.2":"FAIL","2.2.3":"FAIL","2.2.4":"FAIL","2.2.5":"FAIL","2.2.6":"FAIL","2.2.7":"FAIL","2.2.8":"FAIL","3.1.1":"FAIL","2.3.1":"FAIL","2.3.2":"FAIL","2.3.3":"FAIL","2.3.4":"FAIL","2.3.5":"FAIL","3.1.1":"FAIL","3.1.2":"FAIL","3.2.1":"FAIL","3.2.2":"FAIL","3.2.3":"FAIL","3.2.4":"FAIL","3.2.5":"FAIL","3.2.6":"FAIL","3.2.7":"FAIL","3.2.8":"FAIL","3.3.1":"FAIL","3.3.2":"FAIL","3.3.3":"FAIL","3.4.1":"FAIL","3.4.2":"FAIL","3.4.3":"FAIL","3.4.4":"FAIL","3.4.5":"FAIL","3.5.1":"FAIL","3.5.2":"FAIL","3.5.3":"FAIL","3.5.4":"FAIL","3.6.1":"FAIL","3.6.2":"FAIL","3.6.3":"FAIL","3.6.4":"FAIL","3.6.5":"FAIL","4.1.1.1":"FAIL","4.1.1.2":"FAIL","4.1.1.3":"FAIL","4.1.10":"FAIL","4.1.11":"FAIL","4.1.12":"FAIL","4.1.13":"FAIL","4.1.14":"FAIL","4.1.15":"FAIL","4.1.16":"FAIL","4.1.17":"FAIL","4.1.18":"FAIL","4.1.2":"FAIL","4.1.3":"FAIL","4.1.4":"FAIL","4.1.5":"FAIL","4.1.6":"FAIL","4.1.7":"FAIL","4.1.8":"FAIL","4.1.9":"FAIL","4.2.1.1":"FAIL","4.2.1.2":"FAIL","4.2.1.3":"FAIL","4.2.1.4":"FAIL","4.2.1.5":"FAIL","4.2.2.1":"FAIL","4.2.2.2":"FAIL","4.2.2.3":"FAIL","4.2.2.4":"FAIL","4.2.2.5":"FAIL","4.2.3":"FAIL","4.2.4":"FAIL","5.1.1":"FAIL","5.1.2":"FAIL","5.1.3":"FAIL","5.1.4":"FAIL","5.1.5":"FAIL","5.1.6":"FAIL","5.1.7":"FAIL","5.1.8":"FAIL","5.2.1":"FAIL","5.2.10":"FAIL","5.2.11":"FAIL","5.2.12":"FAIL","5.2.13":"FAIL","5.2.14":"FAIL","5.2.15":"FAIL","5.2.2":"FAIL","5.2.3":"FAIL","5.2.4":"FAIL","5.2.5":"FAIL","5.2.6":"FAIL","5.2.7":"FAIL","5.2.8":"FAIL","5.2.9":"FAIL","5.3.1":"FAIL","5.3.2":"FAIL","5.3.3":"FAIL","5.3.4":"FAIL","5.4.1.1":"FAIL","5.4.1.2":"FAIL","5.4.1.3":"FAIL","5.4.1.4":"FAIL","5.4.2":"FAIL","5.4.3":"FAIL","5.4.4":"FAIL","6.1.1":"FAIL","6.1.10":"FAIL","6.1.11":"FAIL","6.1.12":"FAIL","6.1.13":"FAIL","6.1.14":"FAIL","6.1.2":"FAIL","6.1.3":"FAIL","6.1.4":"FAIL","6.1.5":"FAIL","6.1.6":"FAIL","6.1.7":"FAIL","6.1.8":"FAIL","6.1.9":"FAIL","6.2.1":"FAIL","6.2.10":"FAIL","6.2.11":"FAIL","6.2.12":"FAIL","6.2.13":"FAIL","6.2.14":"FAIL","6.2.15":"FAIL","6.2.16":"FAIL","6.2.17":"FAIL","6.2.18":"FAIL","6.2.19":"FAIL","6.2.2":"FAIL","6.2.20":"FAIL","6.2.3":"FAIL","6.2.4":"FAIL","6.2.5":"FAIL","6.2.6":"FAIL","6.2.7":"FAIL","6.2.8":"FAIL","6.2.9":"FAIL"}
```

**Backstory:**
I am writing an audit script that creates this dict at the beginning of the script and then updates the values with something like this:

```
status.get('6.2.4') and status.update({'6.2.4': 'FAIL'})  # # Change value to FAIL
```

or this one:

```
status.get('2.2.6') and status.update({'2.2.6': 'PASS'})  # # Change value to PASS
```

The problem occurs when I try to print out the same dictionary at the end using the following function:

```
def results():
global failcount
global errcount
for (keys, values) in sorted(status.items()):
    print keys + ' ' + values
    if values is 'FAIL':
        failcount = failcount + 1
    if values is 'ERR':
        errcount = errcount + 1
print 'IF MORE THAN 3 FAULTS are FOUND please run the script a second time'
```

The output from running this in my script ends up being:

```
2.2.11 PASS
5.1.5 PASS
5.2.12 PASS
5.2.13 PASS
5.2.14 PASS
5.2.15 PASS
5.2.2 PASS
5.2.3 PASS
5.2.4 PASS
5.2.5 PASS
5.2.6 PASS
5.2.7 PASS
5.2.8 PASS
5.2.9 PASS
5.3.1 PASS
5.3.2 PASS
5.3.3 PASS
5.3.4 PASS
5.4.1.1 PASS
5.4.1.2 PASS
5.4.1.3 PASS
5.4.1.4 PASS
5.4.2 PASS
5.4.3 PASS
5.4.4 PASS
6.1.1 N/A
6.1.10 PASS
6.1.11 PASS
6.1.12 PASS
6.1.13 PASS
6.1.14 PASS
6.1.2 PASS
6.1.3 PASS
6.1.4 PASS
6.1.5 PASS
6.1.6 PASS
6.1.7 PASS
6.1.8 PASS
6.1.9 PASS
6.2.1 CHK
6.2.10 CHK
6.2.11 PASS
6.2.12 PASS
6.2.13 PASS
6.2.14 PASS
6.2.15 CHK
6.2.16 CHK
6.2.17 CHK
6.2.18 CHK
6.2.19 CHK
6.2.2 PASS
6.2.20 PASS
6.2.3 PASS
6.2.4 PASS
6.2.5 PASS
6.2.6 CHK
6.2.7 CHK
6.2.8 CHK
6.2.9 CHK
IF MORE THAN 3 FAULTS are FOUND please run the script a second time
Faults found: 3
Errors found: 0
```

**Steps I have taken to resolve:**

1. Ran through Atom python-debugger
2. Ran through https://pythoniter.appspot.com/ to verify formatting and spacing.
3. Jumped through a number of other questions on here such as [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python) and [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops) and more.
4. Ran through pdb line by line through the function and verified when ran line by line it functioned normally and printed out each value in order.
5. Used the interpreter to simple create the dictionary and then print it with:

   for (keys, values) in sorted(status.items()): print keys + ' ' + values

Which returns this:

```
1.1.16 FAIL
3.2.6 FAIL
5.1.5 FAIL
5.1.6 FAIL
5.1.7 FAIL
5.1.8 FAIL
5.2.1 FAIL
5.2.10 FAIL
5.2.11 FAIL
5.2.12 FAIL
5.2.13 FAIL
5.2.14 FAIL
5.2.15 FAIL
5.2.2 FAIL
5.2.3 FAIL
5.2.4 FAIL
5.2.5 FAIL
5.2.6 FAIL
5.2.7 FAIL
5.2.8 FAIL
5.2.9 FAIL
5.3.1 FAIL
5.3.2 FAIL
5.3.3 FAIL
5.3.4 FAIL
5.4.1.1 FAIL
5.4.1.2 FAIL
5.4.1.3 FAIL
5.4.1.4 FAIL
5.4.2 FAIL
5.4.3 FAIL
5.4.4 FAIL
6.1.1 FAIL
6.1.10 FAIL
6.1.11 FAIL
6.1.12 FAIL
6.1.13 FAIL
6.1.14 FAIL
6.1.2 FAIL
6.1.3 FAIL
6.1.4 FAIL
6.1.5 FAIL
6.1.6 FAIL
6.1.7 FAIL
6.1.8 FAIL
6.1.9 FAIL
6.2.1 FAIL
6.2.10 FAIL
6.2.11 FAIL
6.2.12 FAIL
6.2.13 FAIL
6.2.14 FAIL
6.2.15 FAIL
6.2.16 FAIL
6.2.17 FAIL
6.2.18 FAIL
6.2.19 FAIL
6.2.2 FAIL
6.2.20 FAIL
6.2.3 FAIL
6.2.4 FAIL
6.2.5 FAIL
6.2.6 FAIL
6.2.7 FAIL
6.2.8 FAIL
6.2.9 FAIL
```

**My next steps:**

1. Commenting out functions and testing the script to see if a function is outputting incorrectly or if a local function variable is turning global.
2. Crying profusely.

My main question is what am I missing in creating the dict or did I loop through it incorrectly?

All of my research and symptoms point to the dict itself being formatted incorrectly, but I can't figure out where I went wrong.

**

### RESOLVED

**

[Example](https://dbader.org/blog/difference-between-is-and-equals-in-python) of the difference between is and == in python.

Comment: `is` is not the operator to compare strings for equality.

Comment: We don't have enough information to debug this problem. We're going to need a [mcve].

Comment: Use == instead of 'is' to compare

Comment: can you post how do you exactly update your dictionary?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in your dictionary definition? The dict you provided here looks fine (I'm able to print all keys and values), but maybe you made a typo in your original program.

Comment: One place to look would be `failcount` if that is what you're saying your problem is.  It's a global variable.  Are you sure it's `0` when your function is called?

Comment: I'll check the failcount and see if is versus == changes anything. I will also try to provide the examples.

Comment: @user2357112 can you post that as an answer so I can post it as the correct one. I am sure I tested that previously, but it did resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer. I can't promote your comment to an answer so here it is.

> is is not the operator to compare strings for equality. – user2357112 Dec 7 at 17:28

[Example](https://dbader.org/blog/difference-between-is-and-equals-in-python) of the difference between is and == in python.